# Unix bulk file copy with custom name

Tags: shell, unix, sh

In Unix I have to copy bulk files from one folder to another they are in below form

FILE1_547804_550484_2013-12-19 21.15.32_913.pdf

FILE2_518868_616944_2014-01-03 21.10.49_718.pdf

but while copying to the destination want to remove time part and copy as below:

FILE1_547804_550484.pdf

FILE2_518868_616944.pdf

how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Let me try all below mentioned ways and come back today in evening...Thanks for guidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dst_dir=~/tmp
f='FILE1_547804_550484_2013-12-19 21.15.32_913.pdf'
cp "$f" "$dst_dir/${f%_*-*-* *.*.*_*.pdf}.pdf"
```

Comment: You're missing the `.pdf` at the end of the target filename, it should read `cp $f $dst_dir/${f%_*-*-*\ *.*.*_*.pdf}.pdf` but it is a nice `bash` solution, +1.

Comment: easiest. Thanks for this. Rest solutions also valid so +1 for all. Can you tell me what this technique is called which you did above?

Comment: @DevG It is called [Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 1):

under your directory, try this:

```
ls -1|awk -F_ -v OFS='_' '{o=$0;gsub(/ /,"\\ ",o);NF-=2}$0="cp "o " "$0".pdf"'|sh
```

take one example: (without the ending `|sh` to show the command generated)

```
 echo 'FILE1_547804_550484_2013-12-19 21.15.32_913.pdf'|awk -F_ -v OFS='_' '{o=$0;gsub(/ /,"\\ ",o);NF-=2}$0="cp "o " "$0".pdf"'                                      
cp FILE1_547804_550484_2013-12-19\ 21.15.32_913.pdf FILE1_547804_550484.pdf
```

You can just add the `targetDir` part as you want. this line without modification, will cp to your same directory.

Comment: but where targetDir will go ?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file names using `sed`, or possibly just shell features. Here is an example with `sed`:

```
for i in *.pdf;
do
    n=$(echo "${i}" | sed 's/^\(.\+\)\(\(_.\+\)\{2\}\)\(_.\+\)\{2\}\.pdf$/\1\2.pdf/');
    mv "${i}" "destination/${n}"
done
```